# How to extract source and destination port number from packet in queue of iptables

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming, iptables, netfilter

I am using libnetfilter_queue library. But i couldn't figure out a way to extract port number in the call back function. I am bit new. A detailed help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in the following manner, in the call back function:

```
len = nfq_get_payload(nfa, &buffer);
src_port = *((unsigned short*) (buffer + 20));
dst_port = *((unsigned short*) (buffer + 22));
```

Comment: Why 22 and 20? How do you know how the payload is organized?

Comment: @RodrigoSalazar It was for TCP only and assumes IP header to be 20 bytes long as is in most of the cases, so 20&21 byte i.e. first two bytes of tcp header refer to src port and 22&23 bytes refer to dest port,  as per tcp/ip packet structure

Comment: Thanks for responding, I actually made a question about this the other day and then figured it about the following day myself :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782630/how-does-nfq-get-payload-structure-its-return-data

Comment: It ended up being a lot less 'magical' when you first cast buffer+20 to a tcphdr struct and then pull out the port from there. Seems like in the all other the internet posts about this everyone decides to implement it by directly casting buffer+20 to an unsigned short. Not sure if there's any performance gain to doing it directly, only confusion for anyone less-than-informed who is reading the code.

Comment: @RodrigoSalazar There may not be any observable performance gain, but do mind you are making packets to enter user space from kernel space, which is going to affect your internet speed, depending upon how many iptables rules you have written, and how many packets are directed to your module. If you are only interested in knowing port and ip address in the packets, then using netfilter is not a good choice,in that case you should use libpcap, and code is almost same. Use netfilter when you wish to alter or selectively block the packets.