# What is the correct offset for casting to iphdr and tcphdr?

Tags: c, network-programming, netfilter

Here's a strange behavior of `recv()`.
I'm using `libnetfilter_queue` library and `iptables`in order to store incoming packets into three different queues, depending on their source port (I check this condition thanks to the `iptables` rules written below).

Basically, I get packets whose payload always contains the letter `E`.
Here's my code (for brevity, I omitted the controls on errors).

```
/* bunch of #include <whatineed.h> */

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[3];
    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, queueThread, (void *)0);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, queueThread, (void *)1);
    pthread_create(&threads[2], NULL, queueThread, (void *)2);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The function executed by each thread:

```
void *queueThread(void *queuenum) {
    int fd, rv;
    int queue_num = (int)queuenum;
    struct nfq_handle *h = NULL;
    struct nfq_q_handle *qh = NULL;
    char buf[8192] __attribute__ ((aligned));

    /* queue handling setup */
    h = nfq_open();
    nfq_unbind_pf(h, AF_INET);
    nfq_bind_pf(h, AF_INET);
    qh = nfq_create_queue(h, queue_num, &packetHandler, NULL);
    nfq_set_queue_maxlen(qh, 10000);
    nfq_set_mode(qh, NFQNL_COPY_PACKET, 0xffff);
    memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
    /* Tried to increase socket buffer size, but nothing changes  */
    nfnl_rcvbufsiz(nfq_nfnlh(h), 10000 * 1500);
    fd = nfq_fd(h);
    while ((rv = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) > 0))  {
        printf("queueThread: read %d bytes from file descriptor %d\n", rv, fd);
        nfq_handle_packet(h, buf, rv);
    }
    nfq_destroy_queue(qh);
    nfq_close(h);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The callback function called on each packet I get from `queueThread`:

```
int packetHandler(struct nfq_q_handle *qh, struct nfgenmsg *nfmsg,
    struct nfq_data *nfa, void *data) {
        struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *ph = NULL;
        unsigned char *nf_packet = NULL;
        int pkt_size = 0;
        ph = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(nfa);
        int id = ntohl(ph -> packet_id);
        pkt_size = nfq_get_payload(nfa, &nf_packet);
        printf("packetHandler: pkt is %d byte, it says: %s\n", pkt_size, nf_packet);
        /* Let's check, e.g., its protocol */
        struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) (nf_packet + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
        printf("packetHandler: pkt protocol is %d\n", iph->protocol);
        return nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL);
}
```

After setting the following rules on `iptables`:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --sport 25 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp --sport 5060 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 2
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --sport 5060 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 2
```

Opening a new tab on my browser and loading a page (so, getting packets coming from port 80), here's my output:

```
queueThread: read 148 bytes from file descriptor 4
packetHandler: pkt is 60 byte, it says: E 
packetHandler: pkt protocol is 35
queueThread: read 148 bytes from file descriptor 4
packetHandler: pkt is 60 byte, it says: E 
packetHandler: pkt protocol is 35
queueThread: read 148 bytes from file descriptor 4
packetHandler: pkt is 60 byte, it says: E 
packetHandler: pkt protocol is 35
```

I also tried with `nping` by sending to myself, in another terminal, packets coming from port 25 and port 5060, the result is the same: strange protocol number and always the letter E.
I can't properly cast the payload to `tcphdr` or `udphdr` struct and get the data I need, since I don't know what I got from `queueThread()` and what I pass to `packetHandler()`.

Comment: Why the double condition here? `(rv = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) && (rv >= 0)` ? The right side part is redundant.

Comment: But nevertheless not incorrect: I took away the redundant part and I get always the same `E`.

Comment: What should the packet contain? Not a string data, I guess. Why not to print `pkt_size` bytes in decimal and examine them?

Comment: Truth is I don't care about what the packet contains, since I'm only interested in source/dest address and source/dest port.

Comment: So why do you think `E` is incorrect? Anyway, it can even be not the first byte received as there might be some unprintables before.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain myself clearly: I don't think `E` is correct because when it comes to cast the payload I got from `nfq_get_payload` to `struct iphdr` in order to get the protocol of the packet, I got weird numbers (like 177, and I never saw this protocol).
I know that, generally, browsing the internet should send me packets with protocol number 6 or 17 (TCP or UDP).

Comment: Try running Wireshark and see the actual traffic running, it might help to figure it out.

Comment: I think that if I failed to `recv()` from both `wlan0` (browsing the web) and `lo`(sending packets to myself with `nping`) interfaces, there is something veeery wrong with my program.
Anyway, I'll give a try with Wireshark, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up the arguments here: `printf("queueThread: read %d bytes from file descriptor %d\n", fd, rv);`

Comment: Ops, you are right. Sorry, when I posted the question yesterday I was really tired...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, my mistake was adding `sizeof(struct ethhdr)` to the payload in order to arrive to the IP header of the packet: that's why I always got weird protocol and port numbers, I was in an offset where I was not supposed to be.
Still got `E` but nevermind, I can now read with success protocol and port numbers; sorry for my distraction.

Here's where I found out this: [How does nfq_get_payload structure its return data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782630/how-does-nfq-get-payload-structure-its-return-data)